# How to store related fields in Odoo v8?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

I want to store multiple values using related fields (selection, many2one, and one2many)

```
    class TaskTask(models.Model):
        _inherit = 'task.work.order'
        task_ids = fields.Many2one('task.task','Task')
        name = fields.Char(string='Task', size=64)
        type = fields.Selection(related='task_ids.type', comodel_name='task.task', string='Type', required=True, store=True)
        equipment_id = fields.Many2one(related='task_ids.equipment_id', comodel_name='task.equipment', string='Equipment', select=True, required=True, ondelete='restrict', store=True)
        labor_line_ids = fields.One2many(related='task_ids.labor_line_ids', comodel_name='task.task.labor.line' ,  string='Labor')
```

I use this function to create a new `task_ids`, and I want to add the attributes of the other fields to it.

```
    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        task_obj = self.env['task.task']
        obj = super(TaskTask, self).create(vals)
        task_obj.create({
            'id': obj.id,
            'name': obj.name,
            'type': obj.type,
            'equipment_id': obj.equipment_id.id,
            'labor_line_ids':obj.labor_line_ids,
        })
    return obj
```

But I get errors with the selection, many2one, and one2many. 
I've tried `comodel_name, store=True`, and it is still not working.
I don't have a problem with fields related to `Char` or `Text`.

Errors like:

```
            Integrity Error
    [object with reference: equipment_id - equipment.id]
```

or

```
            Integrity Error
    [object with reference: type - type]
```

If I add `store=True` to `labor_line_ids`, I got:

```
    TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

Comment: Can u tell me what is your current model (database table ) and on which model u want override the create method of the class

Comment: class TaskTask(models.Model): _inherit = 'task.work.order'

Comment: you cant give record set in vals in create function, you must give ids or after create operation assign variable yourself, i don't see any other errors there

Comment: you don't have to assign values manually to related fields. It will automatically get from it's relation.

Comment: Well that the problem, I have a required field and it doesn't register, with or without assigning the values in create function